# jQuery: Problem with ".hasClass()" function in specific case

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a part of my web project:

```js
var $nav = $('#nav'),
  $links = $('li a');

$links.click(function() {
  $links.removeClass("active"); // This will be removed.
  $(this).addClass("active"); // This will be removed.

  var left = this.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    scrollLeft = $nav.scrollLeft();

  $nav.scrollLeft(left + scrollLeft);
});
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

* {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 34px;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#box {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

li {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item-content {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.active {
  background-color: black;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="box">

  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#one" class="active">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#four">Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#five">Five</a></li>
    <li><a href="#six">Six</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="items">
    <div class="item" id="one">
      <div class="item-content">One</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="two">
      <div class="item-content">Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="three">
      <div class="item-content">Three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="four">
      <div class="item-content">Four</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="five">
      <div class="item-content">Five</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="six">
      <div class="item-content">Six</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I will use another function that determines which link is `active`. So `$links.removeClass("active");` and `$(this).addClass("active");` will be removed.

This function should only determine the horizontal scroll position of the navigation.

I would need something like this:

```js
var $nav = $('#nav');

if ($('li a').hasClass('active')) {
var left = this.getBoundingClientRect().left,
scrollLeft = $nav.scrollLeft();
$nav.scrollLeft(left + scrollLeft);
});
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

You can try to work with this code:

```js
var $nav = $('#nav')

if ($("#nav li a").hasClass('active')) {
  var left = this.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    scrollLeft = $nav.scrollLeft();
  $nav.scrollLeft(left + scrollLeft);
}
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

* {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 34px;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#box {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

li {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item-content {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.active {
  background-color: black;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="box">

  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three" class="active">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#four">Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#five">Five</a></li>
    <li><a href="#six">Six</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="items">
    <div class="item" id="one">
      <div class="item-content">One</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="two">
      <div class="item-content">Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="three">
      <div class="item-content">Three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="four">
      <div class="item-content">Four</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="five">
      <div class="item-content">Five</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="six">
      <div class="item-content">Six</div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

In this case, the navigation should be scrolled to link "Three". Why does it not work?

Can somebody help me please? Would be sooooo thankful!

Comment: Not entirely clear what your objective is. Broken code isn't a great substitute for a properly detailed explanation

Comment: I think this line of code is the problem var left = this.getBoundingClientRect().left,

Comment: @charlietfl I updated my question. Is better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe that your javascript should be like this

```js
var $nav = $('#nav')

var active = $("#nav li a.active")[0];
var left = active.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    scrollLeft = $nav.scrollLeft();
$nav.scrollLeft(left + scrollLeft);
```

Comment: You are ingenious! Thank you!! :)))